# Theoretically, is it feasible for the dark matter density to be constant and homogeneous, as dark energy is, and the two to be related?

Tags: cosmology, gravity, dark-matter, dark-energy, galaxy-rotation-curve

I know that currently dark matter and dark energy are separate things, not related and one not deriving from the other. But if both are included in a generalized gravitation theory, the picture can change. Then there may be a correlation between the dark matter and dark energy, and they may then have a common origin.

Comment: The dark matter density is inferred to be inhomogeneous. It isn't of uniform density.

Comment: Voting to re-open. The question is clear and specific. The answer is that we know from cosmological observations that dark matter is *not* homogenous on intergalactic scales.

Comment: In terms of [equation of state](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Equation_of_state_(cosmology)) it is believed that dark matter has $w=0$, while dark energy has $w=-1$.

Comment: @gandalf61 We know it isn't homogeneous on Galactic scales. It probably is (relatively) homogeneous on cosmological scales. How do you answer whether it is "theoretically feasible" based on observations?

Comment: The assumpsion behind the suggestion of uniform homogeneous dark matter density is that the non uniform features and observations be explained by things non dark matter.

Answer (score 0):

That's an excellent question. The correct answer to your question appears to be yes, according to the results of Lu Yin's recent scientific paper on the topic:

Here is an arxiv link to Lu Yin's scientific paper, which supports the theory of positive correlation between energy transfer from dark matter to dark energy: https://arxiv.org/abs/2305.20038v1

> The three dark energy models above have been constrained by the previous research [33–36]. In this work, we are more interested in the evolution of the three models in the local Universe, so we fit free parameters by comparing the data from baryon acoustic oscillations (BAO) [63–66] and Type Ia supernovae (SNIa) [67, 68]. The best-fit results are shown in Tab. II. H0 value from the model and the ICPL model are 70.6986 +0.2639 -0.2601 km/s/Mpc and 70.9338 +0.2549 -0.2515 km/s/Mpc. The fitting result of gamma is a negative number -0.0078 +0.0192 -0.0118, **which means that a high possibility of the energy transfer from dark matter to dark energy**.

However, the distribution of dark matter isn't homogeneous throughout the cosmos, as the of dark matter consisting cosmic web clearly demonstrates, and because that is what fuels the dark kinetic energy phenomenon, dark energy isn't distributed homogeneously either.

I hope this helps.